# WPF TreeView ItemTemplate alighments

Tags: wpf, header, treeview

i have create my own tree-view with multi column Headers using standard wpf controls

- Dock Panel
- DataGrid , Just for creating the columns and having sorting and resizing capabilities. The height of datagrid is only 25 , we only need to show columns not data here.
- The TreeView Control with hierarchy

i have add the image just to understand the problem and the XAML code

The Account Type should be always align at the left no matter how many levels are expanded in the "first column"

somewhere  in the xaml of the TreeViewItemTemplate i lost the idea.. Can anyone help me to fix the alignments

[image]

```
<DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource cust}">
    <Button Command="{Binding rld}" Content="reload" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <!--Unbound DataGrid just to display the headers-->
    <DataGrid Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" x:Name="col0"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AccountType}" Header="Account Type" x:Name="col1"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <!--Actual Binding with Tree View and item Template to display the properties-->
    <TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding rel}">
                <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col0,Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col1,Path=ActualWidth}" ></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AccountType}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeView` naturally indents child items, so its normal what you see.

A possible fix could be to set a negative left margin in the AccountType `TextBlock` with the same value of the indent, therefore neutralizing the gap.
 You need to apply it only if its parent is expanded. This can easily be done modifying a bit your viewmodels.

```
<TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"  Margin="{Binding marginPropertyInVM}" Text="{Binding AccountType}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the size of your first column by changing your template grids column definition to:

```
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col1,Path=ActualWidth}" ></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AccountType}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

This way the first column will only be allowed the remaining width once the 2nd column and indent have been allocated their space.

Comment: @user2160275 ah sorry. You may find this difficult since you are trying to align the datagrid headers and a treeview which aren't actually connected. I'd recommend looking into using a TreeListView as I believe this provides the functionality you want.